# Thread stop of geocalizacion?

Tags: android, gps

desire somehow stop this function "use gps"

```
private void localizacion() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            actUsarGPS.this, "Por favor espere", "BUSCANDO", true);


     handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable runInUIThread = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {

    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

         }
    };

    new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            //handler.post(runInUIThread);
            handler.postDelayed(runInUIThread,1000);
            }
        }.start();
}
```

that the dialog has a cancel button or the back button

and tried to stop him but to no avail.
agradecere them much ..

regards